# javascript window.opener.location.reload() alternative

Tags: javascript

Onclicking a link on a page a popup window appears.This popup window has a form which on submit calls a struts action which has two outputs :- 
if success - the popup should close and parent window should get the message and values updated in parent form
if failure - then on the popup error message should be displayed. the serverside code is ready just dont know how i can implement logically the flow especialy on client window.

i m new to this and need advice on how to implement the same. I tried javascript window opener follwed by window.close() but it does a redirect not a forward thus request attributes are lost and success message is not displayed in parent window.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please add javascript tag to this post -- it might help someone there too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window.location.href=window.location.pathname;

Hope Help You